# NodeJS: crypto-js ouputs a different md5 hash than bash

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, md5, md5sum

So I have the following JS code:

```
const Crypto = require("crypto-js");
const jsonFile = require('path/to/file.json');


console.log(Crypto.MD5(JSON.stringify(jsonFile)).toString());
```

The issue is this console.log produces a different hash than when I md5 the file in bash:

`md5sum /path/to/file.json`

I've tried passing different encodings inside the toString, hashing the javascript object itself, etc but so far I couldn't get the hashes to match.

Comment: if you test with `{}` instead of `jsonFile`, it will produce a hash of 99914b932bd37a50b983c5e7c90ae93b, put `{}` in a file, then do `md5sum file`, it will be the same hash. So to answer, you need to provide the json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that importing, then reformatting your content does not help. I could obtain the same hash by simply reading the file as a string:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const Crypto = require("crypto-js");

const data = fs.readFileSync('./input', 'utf8')
console.log(Crypto.MD5(data).toString())
```

Comment: Yep this was the issue! I assumed using fs would add additional layers to the file and hash something different, but I guess it was the other way around. Thanks!